# JSON response to populate multiple Sections and Rows in tableView

Tags: json, swift

I have the following JSON response:

```
{
"IT":[
    {
    "REPORT_NAME_EN":"Maecenas Eu Arcu",
    "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Numquam optio, doloribus, adipisci recusandae enim."
    }
],
"Marketing":[
    {
    "REPORT_NAME_EN":"Brain Capacity",
    "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
    },
    {
    "REPORT_NAME_EN":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor",
    "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Vitae harum atque possimus distinctio dolores nostrum optio."
    }
],
"Network":[
    {
    "REPORT_NAME_EN":"Quisque Interdum",
    "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Quod, natus, nihil. Repellat dolore, doloremque laborum exercitationem consectetur."
    }
]
}
```

I would like to have it displayed as follow in a tableview with multiple sections (and rows):

```
Section 0: "IT"
Row 0: "REPORT_NAME_EN" & "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN"

Section 1: "Marketing"
Row 0: "REPORT_NAME_EN" & "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN"
Row 1: "REPORT_NAME_EN" & "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN"

Section 2: "Network"
Row 0: "REPORT_NAME_EN" & "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN"
```

I usually append my JSON results to an NSArray but it's the first time I use and receive a multidimensional JSON and I'm having trouble to append:

```
var arrJSON = [[String:Any]]()
do {
    if let data = data,
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]{
        self.arrJSON = [json] as [[String:Any]]
    }
}
```

When I do a arrJSON.count it gives me a result of 1 but it should be 3.

Would I be better off to bring two JSON responses (one to populate my sections and the other for my rows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using "primitive" collection types it's highly recommended to use custom structs for the reports and the sections.

The JSON is decoded with `Decodable` and mapped to an array of `Section`

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    let reports : [Report]
}

struct Report : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let description : String

     private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case name = "REPORT_NAME_EN"
        case description = "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    }
}
```

---

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "IT":        [{"REPORT_NAME_EN":"Maecenas Eu Arcu",
                   "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Numquam optio, doloribus, adipisci recusandae enim."}],
    "Marketing": [{"REPORT_NAME_EN":"Brain Capacity",
                   "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."},
                  {"REPORT_NAME_EN":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor",
                   "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Vitae harum atque possimus distinctio dolores nostrum optio."}],
    "Network":   [{"REPORT_NAME_EN":"Quisque Interdum",
                   "REPORT_DESCRIPTION_EN":"Quod, natus, nihil. Repellat dolore, doloremque laborum exercitationem consectetur."}]}
"""

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[Report]].self, from: data)
    let sections = result.map{ (key, value) -> Section in
        Section(name:key, reports:value)
    }
    print(sections)

} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

---

Declare the data source array

```
var sections = [Section]()
```

In `numberOfSections` return

```
sections.count
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return

```
sections[section].reports.count
```

In `cellforRow` get a report

```
let section = sections[indexPath.section]
let report = section.reports[indexPath.row]
```

In `titleForHeaderInSection` return

```
sections[section].name
```

Comment: Thank you, it's what I needed. I'm getting my JSON response from dataTask and looks like the code "let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)" is not needed, will I encounter issues when comes time to display text with accent? (é, à, è etc..)?

Comment: Right, you have to drop the mentioned line. Regarding the diacritics issue: Is the text UTF8 encoded? If not you might convert the data to UTF8.

Comment: Yes it is, I've made some tests and all is showing up as expected. Once again thank you for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

just try updating your code to this

```
var arrJSON = [[String:Any]]()
do {
if let data = data,
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
        self.arrJSON = json 
    }
}
```